# Execute command line and also allow the command line to output what's happening

Tags: c#

I would like to execute the command line in C# and still have the command line write out its input.

At the moment i'm using this:

```
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo( "Cmd.exe" )
{
    WorkingDirectory = executableDirectoryName,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
};

process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine( arguments.Command );
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine( "exit" );

// Get the output into a string
string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
CommandLineHelper.commandLineOutput = result;
```

This is because one of the processes i'm running takes a long time to load... and ofcourse it doesn't output anything to the command line until the process has finished.

Comment: I guess part of what you are asking is that you do not want to "wait" untill the process has finished but rather move on in your code and do other stuff? But still take care of the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is asynchronous reading, which is done by the [the BeginOutputReadline-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline(v=vs.110).aspx) method, you have activated synchronous reading the way you are doing it.

In short this is what you need to do:

```
// use asynchronous method
myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MyHandler);

// start process
myProcess.Start();

// start the asynchronous read
myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

and define `myHandler`:

```
static void MyHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs output)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(output.Data))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(output.Data); // or whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: Any way I can send data into the MyHandler method?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Do you have an example of what you want to do? The `MyHandler` doesn't have to be static etc, so you can always hook it up with what you need before?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm going to do some work on this tonight (UK) so i'll tell you if anyone's solution works!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is here:

```
string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

[`ReadToEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx):

> Reads all characters from the current position to the end of the stream.

That will always try to read everything, and never return until it's finished.

[`Process.StandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) is a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader.aspx), why not try [`ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) in a loop?

Comment: Nothing - `ReadLine` should block until there is data. If you're doing this in a GUI, you'll probably need to do this in another thread, and post updates back to the GUI thread to update whatever control it is in which you're displaying the output.

Comment: There must be a way of knowing when a process has finished? while( !process.Finished) kind of thing?

Comment: Have you consulted the [MSDN documentation for `Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.aspx)? [`Process.HasExited`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the output as it comes out of the process, rather than waiting for it to finish, use `ReadLine` instead of `ReadToEnd`

```
  while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
  }
```